# CRUD operation using web app via function app as an API to retrieve data from SQL Server through azure function

Tags: sql-server, azure, parameters, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

The problem statement goes as we need to perform a CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operation using a web app form asking for data but the operations should be working as separate functions/methods as `Create()`, `Read()`, `Update()` and `Delete()` in which their respective operations are done in and hereby, these functions must exist in azure functions let's say I used HTTp trigger function.

I was able to do CRUD operations directly from web app to SQL Server and back and then also I was successful in doing it from an Azure function to SQL Server and back using testing in postman tool and in general using the HTTP link. But what I need now is to ask for details like follows.

[image]

This way it asks for details and when I tap on submit it must move from web app to it's respective function which we need to call it from it's onclick.

And there in the function the action must be working.

I am unable to figure out how to connect the web app with Azure functions and send the parameters of that particular textboxes to the functions to be performed.

If anyone could get me with it would be marvelous.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't ask anything.

Comment: I want to pass the texts input of the textboxes to azure functions where the CRUD operations is to be performed. so how do i give this connection between web app and azure function?